# How to add a list picker on Textblock tap event in Wp8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to add a List picker on tap event of Textblock?

Please anyone suggest a simple solution and if possible send a sample code.

I have tried so far the below code. I am getting **PickerPageUri** error while displaying.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the problem? SO isn't a write-me-code site.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange please suggest after seeing the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
  private void tb_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            ListPicker lp = new ListPicker();
            lp.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            lp.Height = 500;
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(lp);
        }
```